# R-Calculate the distance between dataframe elments without using dist() function

Tags: r, classification, distance, k-means, hclust

I have a large dataset (~188000 rows), I want to calculate the distance between my rows so I can then apply the `hclust` function to determine the centers of my dataset and later apply the `kmeans` function to classify my data.

My problem is with the first step which is calculating my matrix distance: using the function `dist` from the package `stats` gave me this error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 132.0 Gb
```

It's clear that it's a RAM problem.

I need to find another way to calculate my distance matrix.

Any clear answer would be so helpful for me.

Comment: Problem is N^2 memory complexity not `dist` implementation.

Comment: @zero323 thank you for the clarification. But how can I proceed in that case.

Comment: Truth be told I am not sure why you want to use hclust before kmeans. If you want to optimize initialization just use kmeans++ / kmeans|| during initialization. I won't point to any R implementation but I am pretty sure there is one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dist function with large number of points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190214/dist-function-with-large-number-of-points)

Comment: @zero323 using the kmeans++ method seemed awesome for me. But, in application in R I encountred this error `Error in kmeans(data, centers = data[center_ids, ], iter.max = iter.max,  : 
  initial centers are not distinct` that I didn't understand.

Comment: @sebastian-c I saw this question before posting my own question. The responses in that one doesn't respond to my needs.

Comment: I am having the same problem, how did you solved this?